# What are the elements of a team development suite?

Tags: project-lifecycle

For small-to-large teams developing software together, what tools are used to form a comprehensive team development framework?

Specifically, I'm looking for a comprehensive list of all the individual functions involved (e.g. source control, bug management, testing tools, project management), not specific product recommendations.  I'm also not restricting the list to a particular methodology (e.g. Scrum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Source control (obviously) including branch management
- Issue tracking (features and bugs), possibly with task reassignment and forwarding, and often things like screen recording
- Individual task management, sometimes integrated with the issue tracking system
- Communication software. Some teams use emails and IMs even within the same building or tweets. There are some tools that integrated within the code so you could "chat around a piece of code". Screen and application sharing are also useful.
- Good build tool.
- Distributed pair programming tools if applicable, shared editors otherwise.
- Similar support in case tools.

Less commonly used but promising tools (from academic background), some now have IDE based versions.

- [Real-time awareness](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~asarma/Palantir) (prevent nerge conflicts by letting you know somebody is working on the same file before you actually write code)
- [In-code social tagging, useful](http://tagsea.sourceforge.net/) for bootmarking specific items
- [In-code contract communication tools](http://emoose.cs.cmu.edu) (e.g., make a caller aware of special expectations in the invoked method as a way of avoiding errors).

Comment: glad I could help. Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

You've hit the major ones in your post:

- IDE (Integrated Development Environment)
- Coding Guidelines (sometimes looked over, but it still helps tremendously)
- Source Control
- Testing Suite (Unit Testing, Test Case/Test Script Management and Tracking)
- Issue Tracking/Bug Reporting
- Build Management

...I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but somebody around here will correct me.

And the one I missed...

- Diagraming software (I.E. Rational Software Modeler, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

A few more:

- Requirements management software
- [Code review software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457534/best-peer-code-review-software)
- Continuous integration tool
- Documentation repository - e.g. Wiki